# What is a worker in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging

From the RabbitMQ [doc](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html)

> One of the advantages of using a Task Queue is the ability to easily
> parallelise work. If we are building up a backlog of work, we can just
> add more workers and that way, scale easily.

I am just not clear what is a worker here, is it the worker queue to which the message is being pushed or the consumer receiver code or some internal rabbitmq daemon process? Can anyone shed some light on this. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no concept of RabbitMQ worker. When they talk about workers, they mean applications that can consume from the same queue to process the tasks in parallel.

This is one of the main advantages of having a message queue. You can scale your process pipeline just by adding more worker applications.